# What is the limit of $ (1 - \frac{1}{n})^{2n}$ as n goes to infinity?

Tags: calculus

$ (1 - \frac{1}{n})^{2n} = ((1-\frac{1}{n})^2)^n = (1-\frac{2}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2})^n$.

If I ignore the $\frac{1}{n^2}$ term inside the parenthesis I have that the limit is $e^{-2}$ which agrees with Mathematica.  Can I ignore this term?  Why?

Comment: Hint. It's cleaner if you use $(X^n)^2$ rather than $(X^2)^n$.

Comment: $$((1-1/n)^n)^2 \to (1/e)^2$$

Comment: write it as $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} [(1+\frac1{-n})^{-n}]^{-2}=\cdots$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ignore the term if you take a logarithm and expand $\ln(1+x)$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ (up to $O(x^2)$).

A better reason here is that $\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2n}=\left(\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\right)^2 \longrightarrow (e^{-1})^2=e^{-2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$\lim \left(1-\frac2n+\frac1{n^2}\right)^n=\lim \left(1+\frac1n\left(-2+\frac1{n}\right)\right)^n=e^{\lim \left(-2+\frac1{n}\right)}=e^{-2}.$

Or you could just do $\lim \left(1-\frac1n\right)^{2n}=e^{2\times (-1)}=e^-2.$
The rule here is $\lim (1+a_n)^{b_n}=e^{\lim (na_nb_n)}.$